# What does the "QueryDeviceInformationVolume" operation in Process Monitor mean?

Tags: sysinternals, process-monitoring, procmon, process-monitor

Seeing an operation called "QueryDeviceInformationVolume" in a SysInternals Process Monitor log when I start a desktop application. Simply trying to get some details about this operation and what it means.

Tried Googling this operation, didn't find anything useful. In fact, I found a GitHub link that *mentions *this operation, with many people asking what it actually MEANS.

Comment: this questions is better asked at https://superuser.com

Comment: Tried searching for "QueryDeviceInformationVolume" at superuser.com. It literally returned 0 results. I'll start a new question to see if I get an answer there.